# How to compare data with the previous day?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I want to create a table where every day will id only which wasn't used yesterday
E.g., I have a table with id and date

```
id  date
1    2021-09-01
2    2021-09-02
10   2021-09-02
14   2021-09-02
20   2021-09-02
3    2021-09-03
20   2021-09-03
14   2021-09-03
4    2021-09-04
10   2021-09-04
5    2021-09-05
6    2021-09-06
```

So the wanted result is

```
1    2021-09-01
2    2021-09-02
10   2021-09-02
14   2021-09-02
20   2021-09-02
3    2021-09-03
4    2021-09-04
10   2021-09-04
5    2021-09-05
6    2021-09-06
```

I'm thinking about smth like this, but not sure about its optimality

```
select *
into transit
from table t0
join table t on t.date = t0.date - 1 and t.id = t0.id

select * 
from table 
except 
select *
from transit
```

Comment: Care to share your own research on the matter? What code have you already tried?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can query the minimal date each id was used:

```sql
SELECT   id, MIN(date)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY MIN(date) ASC
```

**EDIT:**
Based on the clarified requirements, you can use the `not exists` operator to find rows that don't have a corresponding row with the same id on the previous day:

```sql
SELECT id, date
FROM   mytable curr
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable prev
                   WHERE  curr.id = prev.id AND
                          curr.date = prev.date + INTERVAL '1 DAY')
```

Comment: not exactly, edited the dummy data, changed id for 2021-09-04 to show the case when your script doesn't work

Comment: @user458 I think I understand the requirements correctly now. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot! but is there a way to do it by substracting day,not adding?

Comment: @user458 you can reverse the condition: `curr.date - INTERVAL '1 DAY' = prev.date`